# How to make a span icon features as a submit button?

Tags: forms, button, icons, submit

I founded some search-form with no button, they have the search icon featured as a submit button.

Normally they have html and css like this:

```
<form method="get" action="search.php">
  <input type="text" class="" placeholder="search" name="s">
  <span class="icon-search"></span>
</form>

span {
bottom: 0;
cursor: pointer;
line-height: 40px;
opacity: 0.3;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
text-align: center;
top: 1px;
width: 40px;
}
```

And it displays like this:

[image]

This span icon is clickable and works as submit button. How does it work?

Comment: You most probably also have some JavaScript code that takes care of the submit behavior.